# Trouble with a spinner used for data entry

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with two spinners used  for data entry .

I have also a button with the code to insert the selected item values into database.

I have also added code to remove the item from the spinner after data has been successfully added to the database.

The problem is that the first time , it is a success .

If i select another item , fill other required data and click on the button to add , i still get the ID of the previous item which was successfully added. I have added logic to prevent this happening, thus failing.

It works again after closing the activity and restarting it...
Below is the code.

```
public void Add(View v)
    {
        // get tenant id
        // check whether appartment occupied ...and still active
        // check tenants..if same tenant? ask whether want to renew and end previous tenacy
        // test overlapping tenancy
        int pos= spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        TenantList tenant= (TenantList)t.get(pos);
        // get tenant id
        int tenant_id= tenant.get_id();
        int pos1= spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Apartments a = (Apartments)b.get(pos1);
        //get apartment id
        int apartment_id= a.get_id();
        // tenant has a valid tenancy
        if(db.HasValidTenancy(tenant_id)==true)
        {
            // inform user and exit
                        // make a toast
                                    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();         
                                    CharSequence msg ="This Tenant has a vaild running teanancy"+ "\n"+
                                                      "If the tenancy  has expired  first make it  expired"+ "\n"+
                                                       "Before creating a new tenancy";
                                    int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                    return;
        }

        // apartment free?

        if(db.ApartmentNotFree(apartment_id)==true)
        {
            // inform user and exit
            // make a toast
                        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();         
                        CharSequence msg ="This apartment not free"+ "\n"+
                                          "If the tenant left, first teminate the Tenancy";
                        int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return;

        }
        // is same tenant?

         Date sdate=null;
         Date edate=null;
        try {
             sdate = fm.parse(txtviewstartdate.getText().toString());
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
         edate =fm.parse( txtvieweenddate.getText().toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String startdate = fm.format(sdate);
        String enddate =fm.format(edate);
        EditText rental= (EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.editTextRental);
            // test rent ented
        if(rental.getText().toString().length()==0)
        {
            // inform user and exit
            // make a toast
                        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();         
                        CharSequence msg ="You must enter the Monthly Rental amount";                                         
                        int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return;
        }
        double rent = Double.parseDouble(rental.getText().toString());

        db.AddTenancy(tenant_id, apartment_id, startdate, enddate, rent, 0);
        // can u refresh data on spinners?
        // remove apartment
        // remove tenant
        tenantlist.remove(pos);
        apartments.remove(pos1);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dataAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Any ideas? or i will need to restart the Activity in the above code?

Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting your tenants and apartments from lists named t and b:

```
TenantList tenant= (TenantList)t.get(pos);
Apartments a = (Apartments)b.get(pos1);
```

But you are removing them from different lists called tenanlist and apartments:

```
tenantlist.remove(pos);
apartments.remove(pos1);
```

You should be using the same list, or removing it from both, if you have to